# using perl tie::file with utf encoded file

Tags: perl

Can I use `Tie::File` with an output file of utf encoding? I can't get this to work right.
What I am trying to do is open this utf encoded file, remove the match string from the file and rename the file.

Code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Tie::File;
use File::Copy;

my ($input_file) = qw (test.txt);

open my $infh, "<:encoding(UTF-16LE)", $input_file or die "cannot open '$input_file': $!";

for (<$infh>) {
    tie my @lines, "Tie::File", $_;
    shift @lines if $lines[0] =~ m/MyHeader/;
    untie @lines;
    my ($name) = /^(.*).csv/i;
    move($_, $name . ".dat");
}

close $infh
    or die "Cannot close '$input_file': $!";
```

Code: (updated)

```
my ($input_file) = qw (test.txt);
my $qfn_in = $input_file;
my $qfn_out = $qfn_in . ".dat";

open(my $fh_in, "<:raw:perlio:encoding(UTF-16le):crlf:utf8", $qfn_in)
   or die("Can't open \"$qfn_in\": $!\n");

open(my $fh_out, ">:raw:perlio:encoding(UTF-16le):crlf:utf8", $qfn_out)
   or die("Can't open \"$qfn_out\": $!\n");

while (<$fh_in>) {
   next if $. == 1 && /MyHeader/; 
   print($fh_out $_)
      or die("Can't write to \"$qfn_out\": $!");
}

close($fh_in);
close($fh_out) or die("Can't write to \"$qfn_out\": $!");

rename($qfn_out, $qfn_in)
   or die("Can't rename: $!\n");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
my $qfn_in = ...;
my $qfn_out = $qfn_in . ".tmp";

open(my $fh_in, "<:raw:perlio:encoding(UTF-16le):crlf:utf8", $qfn_in)
   or die("Can't open \"$qfn_in\": $!\n");

open(my $fh_out, ">:raw:perlio:encoding(UTF-16le):crlf:utf8", $qfn_out)
   or die("Can't open \"$qfn_out\": $!\n");

while (<$fh_in>) {
   next if $. == 1 && /MyHeader/;
   print($fh_out $_)
      or die("Can't write to \"$qfn_out\": $!");
}

close($fh_in);
close($fh_out) or die("Can't write to \"$qfn_out\": $!");

rename($qfn_out, $qfn_in)
   or die("Can't rename: $!\n");
```

(`:perlio` and `:utf8` are workarounds for bugs that existed back then.)

Comment: On what Perl versions do you need (or not need) the workarounds? I would not think to do them. It's annoying enough that you have to do pop the crlf and then put it back. I almost worked this all out a few weeks ago, but can't seem to find my notes. I wish `:raw` had simply been called `:uncrlf`.

Comment: @tchrist, I saw someone say :utf8 was needed <= 5.8.8. Dunno about 5.8.9. // :raw removed :perlio until very recently. I don't know if the fix is out of bleed if I'm right about it being fixed. // :bytes would be a better name for :raw undoes :encoding too.

Comment: @tchrist, To be clear "removed :perlio" actually means "disabled buffering". I don't know what visible effect on the layers returned by `get_layers`.

Comment: @ikegami - everything works, except for the rename. its still keeping the same file name, I don't see a `.tmp` file also. I made `my $qfn_in = $input_file` (see my original code). Its removing the matched line which is correct, i Just need to get the renaming of the file from `test.txt` to `test.dat`. thanks

Comment: @jdamae, "Doesn't work" is never a good description. What error does it give?

Comment: sorry, there are no errors. the code works where it removes the `MyHeader` from the input file. The input file name though does not change to ".tmp". i posted the code, i am working with now.

Comment: @jdamae, Why would it change to `.tmp`? Are you saying you want it to change to `.tmp`?

Comment: no, i am just using your example. `my $qfn_out = $qfn_in . ".tmp";` i tried naming to whatever extension I want, `.dat` in this case. again, final output is the original file name (`test.txt`, instead of `test.dat`) with the header line removed.

Comment: @jdamae, Tie::File edits in place, so I did the same. If you don't want to edit in place, set `$qfn_out` to the output file and remove the `rename`.

Answer (score 5):

This is underdocumented in the [`Tie::File` perldoc](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tie%3a%3aFile), but you want to pass the `discipline => ':encoding(UTF-16LE)'` option when you tie the file:

```
tie my @lines, 'Tie::File', $input_file, discipline => ':encoding(UTF-16LE)'
```

Note that the third argument is the name of the file to associate with the tied array. `Tie::File` will automatically open and manage the filehandle for you; there is no need to call `open` on the file yourself.

`@lines` now contains the contents of the file, so the next thing to do is check the first line:

```
if ($lines[0] =~ m/pattern/) {
    my $line = shift @lines;
    untie @lines;   # rewrites, closes the file, w/o first line
    my ($name) = $line =~ /^(.*).csv/i;
    rename $input_file, "$name.dat";
}
```

But I concur with TLP that `Tie::File` is overkill for this job.

(My previous answer about opening a filehandle with the correct encoding and passing the glob as the third arg to `Tie::File` won't work, as (1) it didn't open the file in read/write mode and (2) even if it did, `Tie::File` can't or doesn't apply the encoding on both the reading from and writing to the file handle)

Comment: thanks, i tried this too, but am getting these messages: `Filehandle $infh opened only for input at /lib/perl5/5.8/Tie/File.pm line 907, <$infh> line 250.
Couldn't write record: Bad file descriptor at /lib/perl5/5.8/Tie/File.pm line 907, <$infh> line 250.`

Comment: Even my updated answer is pretty dodgy. When `Tie::File` rewrites the file, I don't know if you can trust it to seek and truncate in the right places. IMHO trying to use `Tie::File` just makes this problem a lot harder.

Answer (score 4):

The line:

```
tie my @lines, "Tie::File", $_;
```

Tries to tie `@lines` to a file with the name of each line of `test.txt`. Since it does not seem to be a file with filenames in it, I suspect that that `tie` fails.

What you are probably after is using `Tie::File` on `test.txt`. If you only want to check the first line of that file, you do not need a loop.

So you'd need something like:

```
use autodie;  #handy to check for fatal errors
tie my @lines, "Tie::File", $input_file;
shift @lines if $lines[0] =~ /MyHeader/;
untie @lines;
if ($input_file =~ /(.+).csv/i) {
    move($input_file, $1);
}
```

But there are simpler ways to check the first line of a file. This will check one file:

```
perl -we '$_=<>; print if /MyHeader/; print <>;' test.txt > test.dat
```

Comment: so, you mean this `tie my @lines, "Tie::File", $input_file;'?` I also tried removing the loop. now, i'm getting other messages: `Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//), Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.), Use of uninitialized value in -s,rename, string, stat at perl5/5.8/File/Copy.pm`

Comment: thanks for your input as well. although, i have to do this file open with the encoding check. that particular check has some other chars before the string. so, i'm still figuring out the messgs with the file handle (see reply to mob's answer)